# petapoco how to iterate over query results of type dynamic

Tags: .net, dynamic, petapoco

i recently started using petapoco ORM and came across a scenario where i had to execute a join query. As far as I know if the data isnt specific to one table then the type that can be used as dynamic as shown below:

```
var newsTitles = db.Query<dynamic>(@"SELECT Jobs.JobID, Branches.BranchName,
   Positions.PositionName, Jobs.YearsOfExperience, Jobs.Qualifications, 
   Jobs.Role, Jobs.ExpireyDate 
   FROM Branches 
   INNER JOIN Jobs ON Branches.BranchID = Jobs.Branch 
   INNER JOIN Positions ON Jobs.Position = Positions.PositionID");
```

please let me know if I approached the problem correctly

my question is how can iterate though the returned results in code?
 Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you approached the problem correctly.

You can iterate over the results in the same way you iterate any List in .net

```
 foreach (var item in newsTitles ) {
     // do your thing
 }
```

Comment: Thank you :)
I came across another problem now, I cant databind the result to any data control as its type is dynamic
Any idea on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: You will need to create POCO classes and use them as ViewModels for your databindings